# Many Lookup Relationship for One Object

Tags: apex, soql, lookup, list, relationships

I have the case of an object having two lookup relationship and I call for a list containing both relationship as follows.
This is my Setup code

```
public static List<Job_Application__c> createApplications(){
        List<Job_Application__c> testApplications = new List<Job_Application__c>();
        List<Position__c> testPositions3 = new List<Position__c>();
        List<Candidate_Name__c> testCandidates = new List<Candidate_Name__c>();      
        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            testPositions3.add(new Position__c(Name = 'Test'+ i, Status__c = 'Open - Approved'));
            testCandidates.add(new Candidate_Name__c(First_Name__c ='Bob', Last_Name__c = 'Smith'+i));
        }
        insert testPositions3;
        insert testCandidates;
        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            testApplications.add(new Job_Application__c(Candidate__c=testCandidates[i].Id, 
                                                Position__c=testPositions3[i].Id));
        }
        return testApplications;
    }

    public static List<Review__c> createReviews(){
        List<Position__c> testPositions4 = new List<Position__c>();
        List<Job_Application__c> testApplications2 = new List<Job_Application__c>();
        List<Candidate_Name__c> testCandidates2 = new List<Candidate_Name__c>();
        List<Review__c> testReviews = new List<Review__c>();

        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            testPositions4.add(new Position__c(Name = 'Test'+ i, Status__c = 'Open - Approved'));
            testCandidates2.add(new Candidate_Name__c(First_Name__c ='Bob'+i, Last_Name__c = 'Smith'+i));

        }
        insert testPositions4;
        insert testCandidates2;

        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            testApplications2.add(new Job_Application__c(Candidate__c=testCandidates2[i].Id, 
                                                        Position__c=testPositions4[i].Id));
        }
        insert testApplications2;

        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            testReviews.add(new Review__c(Job_Review__c=testApplications2[i].Id,Rating__c = 1));
        }
        return testReviews;
    }
```

So when I run my test I say I'm expecting 10 Job_Applications but it fails the test and says there is 20.

Is this because it is returning both Position__c and Candidate_Name__c individually from the list?

Or is there an error in my code I'm overlooking.

EDIT
This is the Testing Code

```
    @isTest
    static void testGetPositionsAndApplicants(){
        List<Job_Application__c> result = RecruitingHelper.getPositionsAndApplicants();
        System.assertEquals(10,result.size());
```

and this is the actual query call

```
public static List<Job_Application__c> getPositionsAndApplicants(){
        return [Select Position__c, Candidate__c FROM Job_Application__c];
    }
```

EDIT2: So I figured out that the double size of `Job_Application__c` happens when I run the `Review__c`. Like mentioned earlier these two methods are part of my TestDataFactory.

EDIT3:

```
@isTest
public class RecruitingHelper_test {
    @testSetup 
    static void setup(){
        List<Position__c> testPositions = TestDataFactory.createPositions();
        insert testPositions;
        List<Job_Application__c> testApplications = TestDataFactory.createApplications();
        insert testApplications;
        List<Job_Posting__c> testJobPostings = TestDataFactory.createPostings();
        insert testJobPostings;
        List<Review__c> testReviews = TestDataFactory.createReviews();
        insert testReviews;
    }
}
```

This is the testsetup as requested. I can't find where the data is duplicating but I know for a fact it's somewhere when `Review__c` data is created because I have commented everything out and when I comment that out the test works perfectly for `Job_Application__c`.

Comment: Your provided code here seems to be simple enough that there's not really much room for errors. Since you say that you have a test that's failing, it'd be helpful to include your test class. Also, it's possible that there is some other code (perhaps a trigger, which could be on `Position__c`, `Candidate_Name__c`, or maybe on `Job_Application__c`) or declarative solution (like process builder) that could be throwing a wrench into your testing.

Comment: There I added more information so I narrowed it down where the extra 10 Job_Application__c  it happens when the Review__c creation happens I still can't figure out where though.

Comment: I still think we're missing some pieces of the puzzle here. It isn't clear how your code fragments are connected to each other. Assuming that the snippet for `getPositionsAndApplicants()` is indeed in the `RecuritingHelper` class, your test method isn't doing _any_ setup. Solving this problem requires seeing and understanding the entire path taken through your code. What's creating your data? What code calls your data factory? Do you have an `@testSetup` annotated method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `Job_Application__c` records twice - once in `createApplications()` and once `createReviews()`, where the `Job_Application__c` records are created and inserted inside the test factory. Since each method generates 10 records, your test code will see 20.

Your assertions just don't match your test setup. You can correct this by either factoring your test setup into separate setup increments for individual unit tests, so each test is exposed only to its own specific data set, or by adjusting your assertions to take this into account.

Comment: OK I understand it now so when the setup runs since I have `createReviews()` create `Job_Application__c` those are then inserted to the previous created list from `createApplications()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that you are creating 10 Job_Application__c records in createApplications, so no it is not because it is returning Position__c AND Candidate_Name__c. I agree with Derek F that you may have a trigger that is duplicating it somehow.

Another possible cause may be how you are getting your data. Where is the createApplications method? It looks like it may be a data factory, because I don't see a @isTest or @TestSetup annotation. When are you calling it to create the data? Could you be calling it twice somehow? Or are you using @isTest(SeeAllData=true) ?